# Why can't I add a split environment in a \newenvironment?

Tags: errors, amsmath, split

I wanted a simple environment for making lists of equations, so I made one that includes an equation and a split environment. The code won't compile and the error seems unrelated. The most pressing thing I noticed was the "You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode." The problem is definitely the split environment.
Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{env}
    {\begin{equation}\begin{split}}
    {\end{split}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{env}
    x
\end{env}
\end{document}
```

If I remove the split environment from `env`, everything compiles just fine. Additionally, If the following example compiles just fine. What is the problem then?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    x
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Here is the LaTeX error upon running the MWE.

```
math.tex|11 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{split} on input line 9 ended by \end{env}.
math.tex|12 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{equation} on input line 9 ended by \end{document}.
math.tex|12 error| Missing $ inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing } inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing } inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing } inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing \cr inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing { inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing { inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Extra }, or forgotten $.
math.tex|12 error| Missing $ inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing } inserted.
math.tex|12 error| You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
math.tex|12 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{equation} on input line 9 ended by \end{document}.
math.tex|12 error| Missing } inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Missing $ inserted.
math.tex|12 error| Display math should end with $$.
math.tex|| Emergency stop.
math.tex|| ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: ams alignments need to look ahead to grab the entire content, so as documented you can not hide the end code in other macros (without low level tricks)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so only the split environment uses ams alignments and not the equation environment?

Comment: but you can make your environment similarly look ahead using environ package or xparse `b` argument. rather than use `\newenvironment`

Comment: `split` is defined in `amsmath` `equation` is defined in the latex format

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah. Is there a specific term I should search to find more information on xparse or environ? Will these work in a latex package in a separate file, which is where I actually want to define this environment?

Comment: I poseted an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMS alignments need to grab their body so you can not hide the end code in a macro (as documented in the amsmath documentation) but if you use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` (in current latex or the `xparse` package for older latex you can make the new environment grab the environment body first so that `\end{split}` is visible to `\begin{split}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed in current latex

\NewDocumentEnvironment{env}{+b}
    {\begin{equation}\begin{split}#1\end{split}\end{equation}}
    {}

\begin{document}
\begin{env}
    x
\end{env}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked exactly as I needed!

Comment: Not sure about `+b`… Shouldn't it be `b`? Anyway, this is just a question about what error message one prefers…

Comment: @egreg I wasn't sure either but had to do one or the other

Comment: It compiled fine with `+b`. I don't know the difference though.

Comment: @KNOBPersonal `b` does not allow blank lines (paragraph breaks) `+b` does but as `equation` and `split` do not, the only question is does a blank line give you an error saying they are not allowed in `env` or do you get an error saying they are not allowed in the math environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah. So it does matter... just not in this context. I'll keep that in mind.